# Alors voyons-nous au café à 3 heures

Tags: expressions, oral, impératif

Est-ce qu'on peut dire ces deux phrases ?

> (1) Alors voyons-nous au café à 3 heures.
>   (2) Alors donnons-nous rendez-vous au café à 3 heures.

Comment: Les deux sont correctes.

Comment: @Laure Correctes oui mais pratiquement plus personne ne le dit comme ça aujourd'hui. Le commentaire de Thiht donne l'expression usuelle: « Alors, on se retrouve au café à 3h » ou simplement « Alors, rendez-vous au café à 3 heures ».

Answer (score 5):

Les deux phrases sont justes et compréhensibles.

On préférera cependant employer le verbe "se retrouver" (l'équivalent en anglais serait *to meet*), qui est plus naturel :

> Retrouvons-nous au café à 3 heures !

Comment: À l'oral on préférera même "Rendez-vous au café à 3h", ou en utilisant le pronom impersonnel "On se retrouve au café à 3h".

Answer (score 1):

Cet usage de "Alors" n'est pas grammaticalement correct, mais il est toléré à l'oral en réponse à certaines questions. Sans plus de contexte il vaut mieux se contenter de :

> Voyons-nous au café à 3 heures.

ou

> Donnons-nous rendez-vous au café à 3 heures.

qui sont corrects.