# How to express “I am standing in front of ...”?

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu

The context is telling someone with whom you have a rendez-vous where you are exactly. My try:

> Je me tiens en face/à côté de la piscine municipale.

or

> Tu me trouveras en face/à côté de la piscine municipale

Comment: "Je me tiens/trouve en face/devant..." is alright.

Comment: maybe this question can help https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19329/alors-voyons-nous-au-caf%C3%A9-%C3%A0-3-heures

Comment: merci , c'est très utile ce lien mais le contexte est *après* qu'on ait fixé un RDV  pour dire à quelqu'un qui est déjà parti (en voiture par eg) où on est.
@morganFr thanks a lot

Comment: You could use the very simple "je suis en face de la piscine municipale" or if you are waiting for the person to come "je t'attends en face de la piscine municipale"

Answer (score 2):

In French, you can simply tell

> Je suis devant le/la/les...

If you want to specifiy you are standing (and not sitting), there are not really ways to say it apart from saying it as another information

> Je suis devant le/la/les... . *Je suis debout*.

In general, people prefer to give other informations, such as the one you gave here, about environment

> Je suis devant la/le/les [*location clue*] à côté de [*location clue*]

Answer (score 2):

Your second sentence is not correct. You can not use infinitive verb just after *Tu me trouveras*.

There are multiple options you can use :

> Je suis **en face de** la piscine municipale. (I am **in front of** the swiming pool)
>
> Je me tiens **face à** la piscine municipale. (I **face** the swiming pool)
>
> Je me trouve **devant** la piscine municipale. (I stand **in front of** the swiming pool)
>
> Tu me trouveras **à côté de** la piscine municipale. (You'll find me **next to** the swimming pool)

In this context, you can use either **Je suis**, **Je me tiens**, **Je me trouve** and **Tu me trouveras** as you like.

I tend to discourage the use of [state verbs](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/grammaire/les-verbes-d-etat-162.php) (for example **Être / je suis**) as they often lead to ambiguities.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the ambiguities faced in this particular instance, although sometimes it may be confusion with a passive voice, etc.

Comment: The same goes for english language, see this wikipedia entry : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-Prime